# Meteor 1.3 upgrade warning with react.js

Tags: meteor, reactjs

I'm going through the motions of upgrading a Meteor 1.2 app to 1.3.5.1 and have a large number of console warnings saying something like:

> Warning: You are manually calling a React.PropTypes validation function for the `direction` prop on `MosoTabsScroll`. This is deprecated and will not work in the next major version. You may be seeing this warning due to a third-party PropTypes library. See https://facebook.github.io/react/warnings/dont-call-proptypes.html for details.

I've read the link, and can't see how it applies to my code, which is pretty straightforward and worked perfectly in Meteor 1.2. For example, here is one of the React classes that is generating warnings:

```
import React from 'react';

MosoTabsScroll = React.createClass({

propTypes: {
   direction: React.PropTypes.string,
   active: React.PropTypes.bool
 },

getDefaultProps() {
   return {
     direction: 'left',
     active: false,
   }
},

render() {
   // Set the classNames
   var aClasses = 'btn btn-default btn-shadow scroll-';
   aClasses += (this.props.active ? "active" : "inactive");
   return (
     <a className={aClasses} onClick={this.props.onClick}>
       <i className={"fa fa-lg fa-chevron-" + this.props.direction}></i>
     </a>
   )
 }
});
```

The react package.json under node_modules/react says that it is version 15.3.0.

Comment: Check out the following issue, https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/7131. It's because of the  recent deprecation from React. Not a problem at your end.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an answer, but I've managed to get past these errors by starting from a fresh meteor directory, copying my files into that new directory, and then manually adding back all of the packages that were needed.

So I would put this down to a conflict with some older packages.